Subscribing all pages/components to multiple stores in nuxt 3 using pinia
I've just started transioning from nuxt2/vuex to nuxt3/pinia and I am trying to figure things out.
I created a store to handle my authentication apis and I noticed that
when I am on page /login I can see my store / states in pinia inside vue devtools
but when I go to /index or any other page the states are gone in pinia inside vue devtools
So I figured that there might be a missing configuration or I am doing something wrong
I tried many things and finally I managed to subscribe into the store on the entire app from my understanding doing the following
My app.vue
<template>
  <NuxtLoadingIndicator />
  <NuxtLayout>
    <v-app>
      <NuxtPage />
    </v-app>
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>

<script>
import { useAuthStore } from "@/stores/auth";
export default {
  setup() {
    const authStore = useAuthStore();
  },
};
</script>

My auth store
// store/auth.js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useAuthStore = defineStore("auth", {
  state: () => ({
 successSnackbar: false,
    successMessage: "",
 user: {},
}),
 persist: {
    storage: persistedState.localStorage,
  },|

actions:{ //..},
getters:{ //..},

});

I want to know if this is best practice or even the correct way of doing things in nuxt3/pinia
Now I can see the states on all pages just fine

I would do it like this without pinia, first off, in your nuxt.config
file do this : 

runtimeConfig: 
   { 
     public : { 
       AUTH_SUCCESS_STATUS: false, 
       AUTH_MSG:'' 
   } 
} 

then in your vue files:

    <script setup>
const { $config } = useNuxtApp();

if (process.client) {
  const successStatus = window.localStorage.getItem(
    $config.public.AUTH_SUCCESS_STATUS
  );
}
</script>

this way , the data is persisted on refresh, it can be used globally in all pages and component just by using `window.localStorage.getItem($config.public.AUTH_SUCCESS_STATUS)` and to manipulate it you can use the
other options of localStorage.

another way is to use cookie setup and managing that cookie by useCookie composable
